# Vim: Compile and run C program in build in terminal

Tags: c, vim

This question is quit similar to [Vim [compile and] run shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296192/vim-compile-and-run-shortcut)

but what I want goes a little further. Is it possible to make a shortcut which compile and run the c code in the build in terminal and leave it open afterwards? The solution in the linked post just closes the output afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the trick we used when coding Turbo Pascal and Turbo C++ would solve your problems. Just add a line for some dummy user input in the end of the program.

```
int main(void)
{
    // Your code

    getchar(); // Will not return to Vim before you have entered some data
}
```

Comment: Hello. This fix will solve part of my problem but I still want to run the program in build in terminal (normally opened with :term command)

Comment: @Havsula Yes, I assumed it's not exactly what you want, but I thought it was worth writing it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `!g++ % -o %<` and `:vert term ./%<` together and make it a shortcut.

Here, `!` allows to run external command from vim. `g++` will compile the file, `%` indicates the current file, `<` is used to remove the file extension. `:vert term` is an internal command that lets you use terminal within vim.

Put the code in .vimrc file in home directory. The both commands combined would like,

```
map <F8> :w <CR> :!g++ % -o %< <CR>:vert term ./%<<CR>
```

When F8 button is pressed, vim saves the file then creates the object code. Afterward, with second command vim opens a terminal and runs the program. You will have to `:q` or type `exit` to close the terminal.

Make sure to exit insert mode before you hit F8.

Comment: yeah but how do i handle c programs that use scanf? vim always send eof and i can't find a workaround