# C++ File Requires Library Support

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to compile a simple program from the terminal that utilizes the condition_variable class. Upon building, I get the following error:

> This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` compiler options.

In researching this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363646/compiling-c11-with-g), I added the necessary flag to my make file, but I'm still getting the same error.

Here is my makefile:

```make
CXX=        g++ $(CCFLAGS)
MAIN=       main.o
DATACLASS=  dataclass.o
OBJS =      $(MAIN) $(DATACLASS)

LIBS=       -pthread

CCFLAGS=    -g -std=c++11

all:        main

main:       $(MAIN) $(DATACLASS)
    $(CXX) -o main $(MAIN) $(DATACLASS) $(LIBS)

dataclass:  $(DATACLASS)
    $(CXX) -o dataclass $(DATACLASS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OBJS:.o=.d)

realclean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OBJS:.o=.d) main


%.d:    %.cc
$(SHELL) -ec '$(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< \
    | sed '\''s/\($*\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o $@ : /g'\'' > $@; \
    [ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@'

include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something small and stupid as I'm new to makefiles, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try bringing `CCFLAGS=    -g -std=c++11` before `CXX=        g++ $(CCFLAGS)`.

Comment: `CCFLAGS=    -g -std=c++11` is set **after** your `CXX` variable.

Comment: Why did you use `CCFLAGS` instead of `CXXFLAGS`? I think using `CXXFLAGS` and not adding `$(CCFLAGS)` to `CXX` is better.

Comment: I don't think there's anything called "conditional_variable".

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. So far, no luck. I modified the makefile in accordance with @MikeCAT's suggestion: CXXFLAGS= g++ -g -std=gnu++11 However, I'm still getting that same error...

Comment: @barrt051 Your target definitons are also wrong: `dataclass:` => `dataclass.o:`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Indeed. The default rule will be used to make `dataclass.o` and that doesn't include `CCFLAGS`. But note that `make` variables are normally lazily expanded (or recursively-expanded, as the manual calls it), so there is no problem with definition order. (In Gnu make you can use `:=` instead of `=` to force immediate expansion.)

Answer (score 2):

1. Rewrite `CXX` to `CXX = g++`
2. Change `CCFLAGS` to `CXXFLAGS = -g -std=c++11`, and
3. Rewrite your rules to `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) ...`.

`$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS)` will then be replaced with `g++ -g -std=c++11`. This is more of a standard method for defining a `makefile`. Here is a snippet of the resulting `makefile`.

```make
CXX = g++
MAIN = main.o
DATACLASS = dataclass.o
OBJS = $(MAIN) $(DATACLASS)

LIBS = -pthread

CXXFLAGS = -g -std=c++11

all: main

main: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $? -o $@ $(LIBS)
```

---

As a side note, are you sure this rule should be defined as such?

```make
dataclass: $(DATACLASS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $? -o $@ $(LIBS)
```

Should the target not be `dataclass.o` or `$(DATACLASS)` and the prerequisite some other file?

---

**Note**: I've also included some `make` [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) to tidy up the `makefile` rules.

- `$?` - is replaced by all prerequisites
- `$@` - is replaced by the target name