# Why aren't vectors running in codeblocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, block

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    vector<int> myvector{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };  
    for (auto it = myvector.begin(); 
         it != myvector.end(); ++it) 
        cout << ' ' << *it; 
    return 0; 
}
```

*Everytime I run vector , error message will say... "it must be initialized by constructor, not be'{...}'*

*And; could not convert '{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}' from '' to std::vector"*

**What should I do?**

Comment: Sounds like you need to [enable C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18174988/10077).

Comment: Initializer lists are a C++11 feature (I think). You need to change your project properties to use the relevant compiler flag (can't remember how to do this, sorry). Hopefully that sets you in the right direction

Comment: Code::blocks is often shipped with an older compiler that understands C++11 but does not enable it by default. [This should be of help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler) You can also [update the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2). Updating the compiler is a bit more complicated, but worth it in my books

Comment: I don't trust an ide for C++ that doesn't even enable C++11 in 2021

Comment: dupe of [Vector c++ 98 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173078/vector-c-98-error) and others, found by searching for the quoted error

Answer (score 1):

You would have to change from -std=C++98 to about -std=-C++11 or more. This can be done in your compiler settings.

1. Go to settings
2. Click on compiler...
3. on the compiler settings tab, you would find the options, so choose (check it within the checkbox) -stf=c++11 or upwards
4. Click OK and run your program again.