# decltype() in c++ causes compile errors

Tags: c++, decltype

I am new to c++. In a tutorial i was reading about `auto` and `decltype` and tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int foo = 0;
decltype(foo) bar; 
bar = 22;


int main(){
    cout<<foo;
    cout<<bar;
    }
```

and i get this error upon compilation:

**tst.cpp.6:1: warning: identifier 'decltype' is a keyword in C++11**

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you explicitly enable c++11 features in your build chain?

Comment: Btw, it's not an error, it's a warning. Difference: Error = something is wrong, compilation was aborted. Warning = something looks suspicious to the compiler, but it has continued compilation anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `-std=c++11` flag (command line argument) to your compiler:

```
g++ -std=c++11 tst.cpp -o your_program_name.exe
```

For more reading: [Compiling C++11 with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363646/compiling-c11-with-g)