# Raw String ‘R’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I'm Learning c++ , so pardon me
I'm trying to store a Raw String in C++ 
but i get `‘R’ was not declared in this scope`
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string nx =R"('(;<\"/  )3-)";
    std::cout << nx;
}
```

and [Here](http://cpp.sh/8hsws) is a online compiler which compiles it without any problem

probably its something with my compiler im on ubuntu 15.10 and latest g++

Comment: It's because you only know how to enable C++14 via GUI.

Comment: @LogicStuff Im Sorry I'm just learning , so dont know how to do it and i dont know what to search about it because when i searched for this type of problem i did not found anything useful or related

Comment: Raw Strings require C++11 or above; If you select option C++98 in the online compiler, then you will get the same error as with g++. How do you call g++?

Comment: @stephan-lechner I started learning c++ so i use g++ test.cpp -o test

Comment: Try `g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra test.cpp`. Also, don't call your test programs `test` because at some point you're going to confuse yourself and accidentally run the system `test` command instead, which produces no output.

Comment: @melpomene thanks for your answer it works :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raw Strings require C++11 or above; If you select option C++98 in the online compiler, then you will get the same error as with g++.
See the following command for enabling C++11 in g++ (taken from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10363883/2630032), please upvote when applicable):

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 your_file.cpp -o your_program
```

Comment: thanks it works as you said "or above" i used -std=c++14