# error: too many initializers for a struct

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I'm trying some code with c++11,

```
  struct Data {};

  struct B {
    B(Data data) : m_data{data} {}
    Data m_data{};
  };
```

it complains 
error: too many initializers for 'Data'

what is wrong?

[UPDATE] thanks guys, there is something wrong with my toolchain configuration.

Comment: Compiles clean for me g++ 5.1.0 (in full SO paranoid mode)

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve]?

Comment: Which compiler? What compiler flags?

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling with the flag `-std=c++11`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling C++11 with g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363646/compiling-c11-with-g)

Comment: I think it's time we started closing so-called C++11 questions, in which the problem was the OP _wasn't_ compiling C++11, as "no longer reproducible".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that error string when you do not enable c++11 mode or later in older GCC compilers (that defaults to c++03).

> ```
> main.cpp:4:31: error: too many initializers for 'Data'
> B(Data data) : m_data{data} {}
> ```

See it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e056c058b069c62). Although newer versions of GCC will give you more helpful diagnostics to enable c++11 mode.

So, just add to your compiler invocation:

```
-std=c++11
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct c++11, but maybe you are not compiling in C++11 mode.

Many compiler still defaults to C++98, and you typically need to activate a command line switch (or an option in your IDE) to enable C++11 syntax.

I've added to your code a small main:

```
int main()
{
    Data d;
    B b(d);
}
```

... and it compiles clean both with gcc 5.x and clang 802 (xcode 8 version), provided I add on the command line:

-std=c++11