# Initializing list of strings in c++11

Tags: c++, list

I was trying to initialize a list of strings in c++11 using the following code, and its failing with various reasons. The error says that I need to use constructor to initialize the list, should I use something like `list<string> s = new list<string> [size]` ?  What am I missing here?

```
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
      string s = "Mark";
      list<string> l  {"name of the guy"," is Mark"};
      cout<<s<<endl;
      int size = sizeof(l)/sizeof(l[0]);
      for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
             cout<<l[i]<<endl;
      }
      return 0;
 }
```

I/O is

```
 strtest.cpp:8:47: error: in C++98 ‘l’ must be initialized by constructor, not 
 by ‘{...}’
 list<string> l  {"name of the guy"," is Mark"};
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: To get the number of elements in the list `l`, call `l.size()`. That `sizeof` dance only works for C-style arrays.

Comment: Your error message appears to be telling you that you are building with C++98 not 11

Answer (score 11):

You are using a compiler of c++98 instead of c++11.using this if you are using gcc

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o strtest strtest.cpp
```

you can replace *c++11* with *gnu++11*

Comment: Thanks, I hardly realized that I was not using c++11, I guess I was scared at the amount of errors I saw and didn't catch this one

Answer (score 10):

List initializers are only available in C++11.  To use C++11 you probably have to pass a flag to the compiler.  For [GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363646) and Clang this is `-std=c++11`.

Also, `std::list` does not provide a subscript operator.  You could either use a `std::vector` as in the other answer or you use a range-based for loop to iterate over the list.

Some more hints:

- [never do `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721)
- whitespace is free

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::string s = "Mark";
  std::list<std::string> l {"name of the guy"," is Mark"};

  for (auto const& n : l)
    std::cout << n << '\n';
}
```

Comment: why should you never use using namespace std?

Comment: @Makogan See the link.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem here is that you are using lists. In C++ lists are doubly linked lists, as such the [] doesn't make any sense. You should be using vectors instead.

I'd try:

```
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
      string s = "Mark";
      vector<string> l = {"name of the guy"," is Mark"};
      cout<<s<<endl;
      for (int i=0;i<l.size();i++) {
             cout<<l[i]<<endl;
      }
      return 0;
 }
```

instead

EDIT: as others pointed out, make sure you are compiling with c++ 11 and not c++ 98

Comment: Thanks!, what would be use case for using lists then? Can you please explain only if its not too complex?

Comment: Well do you  know what a linked list is?

Comment: I do, its just that the term "list" is so straightforward and compelling for me to use it in a "regular" context.  I guess I was asking why would some one name a doubly linked list  as just "list"?

Comment: @AparnaChaganti The answers to the following question should help: [vector vs. list in STL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2209224/445976)

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer to this problem is to just simply copy the contents of one list into another list hope it helps :)