# warning: inline variables are only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’ how to suppress it?

Tags: c++, c++11

Using below function in one of the .h file.
if i am using function deceleration without inline getting multiple definitions error and now after adding inline getting above warning so help me to suppress the warning i mean how to fix the warning.

```
inline void (*log_fcn)(int level, std::string format, unsigned int line_no, std::string file_name, ...);
```

Comment: I removed the C tag since your code is clearly C++.

Comment: Do you insist one whatever older C++ version you are currently compiling with? Why don't  you switch to one of those which do support what you are trying to use? What I mean is that you do not want to suppress the warning, you want to fix it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. `log_fcn` is not a function, but a variable ( of type function pointer).

Comment: Note that this line does not declare a *function*, it declares a *function pointer*, which does not make sense to be `inline`.

Comment: yes i need to fix it.

Comment: `log_fcn` is a pointer to a function and not a name of the function. That is, you're not actually declaring a function named `log_fcn`.

Comment: So how about setting up for building with C++17? Are you aware of your configs which seem to force an older version? Can you show it? I.e. how exactly do you compile/build?

Comment: Anoop Rana yes its a function pointer later point i am giving address of one function to it.

Comment: build is with automake and normall g++ compiler bases Yunnosch.

Comment: @MNAdarshKumar Are you sure that you're using C++17? If yes then this should work. Also refer to [How do inline variables work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work). **Inline variables are a C++17 feature.**

Comment: Please only tag the version of c++ you are using

Comment: @AnoopRana i am using c++ 11 how can i upgrade it.

Comment: @MNAdarshKumar For one you can use manually the command `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o your_program` to compile your program with C++17 instead of C++11. Also refer to [Compiling C++11 with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363646/compiling-c11-with-g). In the above linked question, just change c++11 to c++17 wherever applicable.

Comment: @AnoopRana i am using automake to build how it can be done

Comment: Why do you feel the need for an inline variable? What's wrong with a "normal" global variable?

Comment: @MNAdarshKumar You can use `extern` with C++11 as shown below in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Using below function in one of the .h file.

It is not a function. It is a variable of function pointer type.

> how to fix the warning

Option 1: Use C++17 or later language version.

Option 2: Don't use C++17 features like inline variables. To use a non-inline namespace scope variable, you can declare it extern in the header, and define it in one translation unit.

Comment: /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:622: undefined reference to `log_fcn[abi:cxx11]'
/usr/bin/ld: component_CTL/src/BoardSelect.o: in function `Environment::BoardSelect::parse_board_name(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
/home/adarsh/GIT_NEW_COMPONENTCTL/bosch-linuxandroid-dev/code/component_CTL/src/BoardSelect.cpp:86: undefined reference to `log_fcn[abi:cxx11]'
/usr/bin/ld: component_CTL/src/BoardSelect.o:/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:622: more undefined references to `log_fcn[abi:cxx11]' follow getting above error message after using extern

Comment: @MNAdarshKumar Did you do `and define it in one translation unit.`?

Comment: void (*log_fcn)(int level, std::string format, unsigned int line_no, std::string file_name, ...);
 log_fcn = reinterpret_cast<void (*log_fcn)>(l); getting error for this defination

Answer (score 0):

`inline` variables are a C++17 feature. But since you're using C++11 you can make use of `extern` as shown below:

**header.h**

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

#include <string>
//THIS IS A DECLARATION. Note the use of extern keyword here. 
extern void (*log_fcn)(int level, std::string format, unsigned int line_no, std::string file_name, ...);

#endif
```

**source.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"
void func(int level, std::string format, unsigned int line_no, std::string file_name, ...)
{
    
}
//this is definition
void (*log_fcn)(int level, std::string format, 
                unsigned int line_no, std::string file_name, ...) = func;
//------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^--->initializer
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    
}
```

[Working demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HoGPWZ6SSGdCv3dx).

Comment: arana /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:622: undefined reference to log_fcn[abi:cxx11]' /usr/bin/ld: component_CTL/src/BoardSelect.o: in function Environment::BoardSelect::parse_board_name(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)': /home/adarsh/GIT_NEW_COMPONENTCTL/bosch-linuxandroid-dev/code/component_CTL/src/BoardSelect.cpp:86: undefined reference to log_fcn[abi:cxx11]' /usr/bin/ld: component_CTL/src/BoardSelect.o:/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:622: more undefined references to log_fcn[abi:cxx11]' follow getting above error message after using extern

Comment: @MNAdarshKumar In my answer i have given a link to a [working demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HoGPWZ6SSGdCv3dx), just copy-paste from that demo and that should work. The error that you're getting is a *linker error* that suggest that you had not placed the definition of `log_fcn` in a source file(.cpp). So just add a corresponding definition in the source file.

Comment: @MNAdarshKumar Don't forget to add the **definition** `void (*log_fcn)(int level, std::string format, unsigned int line_no, std::string file_name, ...);` in the source file and the **declaration** `extern void (*log_fcn)(int level, std::string format, unsigned int line_no, std::string file_name, ...);` in the header file.

Comment: void (*log_fcn)(int level, std::string format, unsigned int line_no, std::string file_name, ...);
 log_fcn = reinterpret_cast<void (*log_fcn)>(l);