# thread library is not working on c++ netbeans ide 16

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw, netbeans-8

I was using thread on my netbeans ide 16 and it was giving error(main.cpp:14:4: error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope)

i tried adding -pthread and -lpthread in additional options but it didnt work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGRZD.png)

Comment: Never `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Using pthreads are not std::thread

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you really want help with your problem you should take the [*tour of StackOverflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check out [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then check out [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/845568) and [*creating a minimal,reproducable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You should have `#include <thread>` [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) and if that does not work your compiler is very old but maybe it still has support for the 2011 standard: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363646/compiling-c11-with-g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363646/compiling-c11-with-g)

Comment: My guess would be you're using an old version of mingw with no std::thread support

Comment: I expect the same. Using this: [https://www.msys2.org/#installation](https://www.msys2.org/#installation) will install the most current version of MinGW.